# Creating an IPAddress object from an unsigned int

Tags: programming

If I create an IPAddress object using a decimal IP address, it appears to be reversed.
What am I doing wrong? See code examples below.

```
IPAddress addressOne(192,168,50,1);
Serial.print(addressOne);                // ==> prints "192.168.50.1"

//The decimal version of 192.168.50.1 is 3232248321
unsigned int iAddress = 3232248321;
IPAddress addressTwo(iAddress);
Serial.print(addressTwo);                // ==> prints "1.50.168.192"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just found out that this `IPAddress` constructor interprets its
parameter in little endian order. Then encode your address as
little-endian:

```cpp
//The decimal version of 192.168.50.1 is 20097216
unsigned int iAddress = 20097216;
```

Comment: Wow! I just learned something! Thanks!